# Does any OS have an API for rearranging blocks within a file if they are aligned with FS blocks?

Tags: memory, operating-system, fs

Let's assume there is a binary file format, and it contains a header and blocks of data which location and size is deriveable from the info in tue header.

Let's assume that the data can span multiple blocks and has a certain structure within it. I.e. it may be an uncompressed video stream.

Let's assumme we want to add some data into the middle of file. We can copy the tail into a separate temp file, then overwrite the block formerly helonging to the tail, then write the tail back after it. Feels like inefficient!

If the file format was designed a certain way, i.e. if the header determined the order of blocks, then it'd be possible to just append the block into the end and then rewrite just the header. We assume the file format is not designed this way.

We also assume tuat the data must be in a single file.

If we assumme that all the blocks within file are aligned with blocks of FS, the data about the blocks in the header is redundant and it may be possible to modify the FS metadata to allocate a fs block and write the new data into it and then modify the chain of fs blocks to have the newly-created block be in the right place.

Does any OS provide such an API?

Comment: I have occasionally wished for this too, along with a queue file.  I don't know of any file system that provides it.  I suspect that it would be very difficult to implement and require support at the lower levels of the overall system, possibly including the drive controller. Such a compound operation may risk the integrity of the file system without another level of journalling/commit:(